# Using dynamic sql to automate inserts in different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, dynamic-sql

I am trying to automate multiple inserts into multiple tables.

Basically, I have one temp table, with Customer codes and I added a row number. I also have a source tables, which contains the customer codes and personal info. Now I would like to insert alle the Person ID's from customer 1 into #1, all the PersonID's from customer 2 into #2 and so on.

I used this code, but it generates an error:

```
DECLARE @Customer_Code INT
DECLARE @Row INT = 1
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)


WHILE @Row = SELECT MAX(Rij) FROM #M

BEGIN 
    SELECT @Customer_Code = Customer_Code FROM #M WHERE RowNr = @Row

    SET @SQL = 

    'SELECT PersonID 
    INTO #@Customer_Code
    FROM T_Sourcetable 
    WHERE YEAR (Date) = 2016 
      AND Customer_Code = @Customer_Code'
    
    EXECUTE (@SQL)
       
    SET @Row = @Row + 1
    SET @SQL = ''
END
```

Could anyone please help me here. Thanks in advance.

PS. I'm using MS SQL Server 2008.

Sample data:

## M: Customer_Code AND RowNumber

1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4

In reality, obviously Customer code != RowNumber.

Source Table: COLUMNS (Customer_Code    PersonID)

```
1, 8 ,
1, 9 ,
1, 10,
1, 11,
2, 9 ,
2, 12,
2, 13,
2, 14,
3, 8 ,
3, 14,
3, 15,
3, 17,
4, 8 ,
4, 10,
4, 12,
4, 14
```

Result should be:

```
Table #1: 
PersonID
8
9
10
11

Table #2
PersonID
9
12
13
14

Table #3
PersonID
8
14
15
17

Table #4
PersonID
8
10
12
14
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample data as DDL+DML (Create and insert statements) and desired results.

Comment: Looks kind of scrappy, not used to this editor. Hopefully you can figure out what I mean.

Comment: I don't want to figure out what you mean, I want to copy and paste the sample data and have it ready for work.

Comment: Edited again. Two columns in source table. Output that I wish is clear.

Comment: Mixing temporary tables and dynamic sql is messy. If the temporary table is created in dynamic sql it will only be available in the dynamic sql context, but will not be available in the context that executes the dynamic sql.
I think you better describe your final goal so that perhaps someone can help you find a better solution. (Is this an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?) btw, I've edited your question again to show you exactly what I mean by sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `WHILE @Row`. This is not a boolean expression, you are probably looking for something like `WHILE @ROW <= SELECT MAX(Rij) FROM #M`.

Furthermore, you are executing the `SELECT...INTO` multiple times. The second time it gets executed, the table `#@Customer_Code` already exists, so you can't do `SELECT...INTO` but have to use `INSERT` instead. It's best to define the table before hand. **edit:** I suppose you are trying to make a temporary table for every `Customer_Code`, in which case you should append the variable correctly. The same goes for `AND Customer_Code = @Customer_Code'`, the variable is appended as the literal string, not as the value it holds.
The query that gets executed for every row in `#M` is:

```
SELECT PersonID 
    INTO #@Customer_Code
    FROM T_Sourcetable 
    WHERE YEAR (Date) = 2016 
      AND Customer_Code = @Customer_Code
```

This is obviously not your intention. What you need is:

```
'SELECT PersonID 
    INTO #'+ @Customer_Code + 
    'FROM T_Sourcetable 
    WHERE YEAR (Date) = 2016 
      AND Customer_Code = '+ @Customer_Code
```

In future, if you receive an error message, the least you can do is tell us what the error message actually says!

Comment: Ok, you are right: Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '
   AND Customer_Code= @Customer_Code'.

Comment: What Does #m Contain

Comment: Thanks @HoneyBadger: This seems to be what I am looking for. Still get an error, Incorrect syntax near T_Sourcetable.

Comment: Your posted query, sample data and comments don't fit each other. What is `#M`, now you are talking about `T_Sourcetable`? You are not making it easy to get the help you need.

Comment: People can also edit my input. Makes it a little more challenging for me. Basically, I have one temp table #m, with Customer codes and I added a row number. I also have a source tables, which contains the customer codes and personal info.

Comment: Re-edited the question again. Thanks for the input / patience thus far.